# Optimize slow sql query with calculations where there are missing rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, calculated-field

I'm working on a `SQL` query containing forecasts. Normally there should be forecasts for each day during a given period. However, sometimes there are cases where the forecast for a particular day in the given interval is missing, and when this happens, I'd like to perform a calculation to estimate the forecast based on the existing forecasts for the same day and which belong to the same area.

I've put together a query, but it's really slow and taking up a lot of memory. Could anyone help me in the right direction?

```
declare @startDt date = :startDate
declare @endDt date = :endDate; 

with  AllDates as
(
   select  @startDt as dt
   union all
   select  dateadd(day, 1, dt)
   from    AllDates
   where   dateadd(day, 1, dt) <= @endDt
)

select  
      dt, 
      m.date, 
      p.lp, 
      p.electricityArea, 
      maxCapacity, 
      sum(hour00_01) b, 
      SUM(maxCapacity) as c, 
      ISNULL( ISNULL(hour00_01, maxCapacity * ( SELECT sum(hour00_01)/sum(maxCapacity) 
                                                   FROM tbl_p p2, 
                                                        tbl_m m2 
                                                   WHERE netArea = p.netArea 
                                                     AND plantType = '2'  
                                                     and date = dt 
                                                     and m2.lp = p2.lp 
                                                     AND (inputType = :forecastType) )), 
                                maxCapacity * ( SELECT sum(hour00_01)/sum(maxCapacity) 
                                                   FROM tbl_p p3, 
                                                        tbl_m m3 
                                                   WHERE electricityArea = p.electricityArea 
                                                     AND plantType = '2'  
                                                     and date = dt 
                                                     and m3.lp = p3.lp 
                                                     AND (inputType = :forecastType))) hour00_01, 
      ISNULL( ISNULL( hour01_02, maxCapacity * ( SELECT sum(hour01_02)/sum(maxCapacity)
                                                    FROM tbl_p p2, 
                                                         tbl_m m2 
                                                    WHERE netArea = p.netArea 
                                                      AND plantType = '2'  
                                                      and date = dt 
                                                      and m2.lp = p2.lp 
                                                      AND (inputType = :forecastType))), 
                                 maxCapacity * ( SELECT sum(hour01_02) / sum(maxCapacity) 
                                                    FROM tbl_p p3, 
                                                         tbl_m m3 
                                                    WHERE electricityArea = p.electricityArea 
                                                      AND plantType = '2'  
                                                      and date = dt 
                                                      and m3.lp = p3.lp 
                                                      AND (inputType = :forecastType))) hour01_02,
      **...[all 24 hours]...**
   from
      AllDates ad
         cross join tbl_p p
         left join tbl_m m
            on p.lp = m.lp
            and m.date = ad.dt 
            and m.inputType = :forecastType
   where 
          p.plantType = '2' 
      AND agreementStart <= :startDate1 
      AND agreementEnd >= :endDate1
   GROUP BY 
      dt, 
      m.date, 
      p.lp, 
      p.electricityArea, 
      maxCapacity, 
      p.netArea, 
      p.electricityArea, 
      hour00_01, hour01_02, hour02_03, hour03_04, hour04_05, hour05_06, 
      hour06_07, hour07_08, hour08_09, hour09_10, hour10_11, hour11_12, 
      hour12_13, hour13_14, hour14_15, hour15_16, hour16_17, hour17_18, 
      hour18_19, hour19_20, hour20_21, hour21_22, hour22_23, hour23_24
   ORDER BY 
      p.lp, 
      dt option  (maxrecursion 0)
```

Any idea how this could be optimized?

Table structures as pasted into comments vs edit of original question

```
tbl_p

COLUMN_NAME        DATA_TYPE   CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH   IS_NULLABLE 
plantId            int         NULL                       NO
lp                 nchar       45                         YES
unitId             nchar       45                         YES
plantType          int         NULL                       YES
electricityArea    nchar       45                         YES
netArea            nchar       45                         YES
maxCapacity        int         NULL                       YES
yearlyCapacity     int         NULL                       YES
numberOfPlants     int         NULL                       YES
manufacturer       nchar       45                         YES
groundLevel        nchar       45                         YES
altitudeLevel      nchar       45                         YES
updatedFromIp      nchar       45                         YES
xCoordinates       nchar       45                         YES
yCoordinates       nchar       45                         YES
plantStatus        nchar       10                         YES
agreementStart     datetime    NULL                       YES
agreementEnd       datetime    NULL                       YES 

tbl_m is (with some removed columns to fit it here): 
COLUMN_NAME        DATA_TYPE   CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH   IS_NULLABLE 
id                 int         NULL                       NO
lp                 nchar       45                         YES
timeStampReturned  datetime    NULL                       YES
date               date        NULL                       YES
hour00_01          decimal     NULL                       YES
hour01_02          decimal     NULL                       YES
hour02_03          decimal     NULL                       YES
...
hour21_22          decimal     NULL                       YES
hour22_23          decimal     NULL                       YES
inputType          nchar       45                         YES
```

Comment: tough task, could you post your tables definition?

Comment: Also which database are you using ?

Comment: tbl_p is:
ORDINAL_POSITION COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH IS_NULLABLE
1 plantId int NULL NO
2 lp nchar 45 YES
3 unitId nchar 45 YES
4 plantType int NULL YES
5 electricityArea nchar 45 YES
6 netArea nchar 45 YES
7 maxCapacity int NULL YES
8 yearlyCapacity int NULL YES
9 numberOfPlants int NULL YES
10 manufacturer nchar 45 YES
11 groundLevel nchar 45 YES
12 altitudeLevel nchar 45 YES
13 updatedFromIp nchar 45 YES
14 xCoordinates nchar 45 YES
15 yCoordinates nchar 45 YES
16 plantStatus nchar 10 YES
17 agreementStart datetime NULL YES
18 agreementEnd datetime NULL YES

Comment: tbl_m is (with some removed columns to fit it here):
ORDINAL_POSITION COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH IS_NULLABLE
1 id int NULL NO
2 lp nchar 45 YES
3 timeStampReturned datetime NULL YES
4 date date NULL YES
5 hour00_01 decimal NULL YES
6 hour01_02 decimal NULL YES
7 hour02_03 decimal NULL YES
8 hour03_04 decimal NULL YES
9 hour04_05 decimal NULL YES
10 hour05_06 decimal NULL YES
11 hour06_07 decimal NULL YES
12 hour07_08 decimal NULL YES
13 hour08_09 decimal NULL YES
14 hour09_10 decimal NULL YES
15 hour10_11 decimal NULL YES
56 inputType nchar 45 YES

Comment: Using SQL server 2008

Comment: A few points.  One, you probably don't need a cross join.  A left join from AllDates should suffice.  Two, if you want people to help you, make your code easy to read.  Do you enjoy using horizontal scroll bars?  Finally, if you are going to mix fact and fiction in the same report, you might want to indicate which is which to the people reading it.

Comment: Aside from getting table structures listed, you should always table.column or alias.column all your queries since we don't know which table the hours columns are associated, maxCapacity, date, etc.  Big deal, especially if anyone to follow after you.

Comment: The nested isnulls might be slowing down production.  A case construct might be a better approach.

Comment: @DRapp Thank you for pasting it in a more readable format.

Comment: @DanBracuk That sounds reasonable. So a case construct with something like this would be faster? 
CASE hour00_01 WHEN null THEN sum(hour00_01)/sum(maxCapacity) FROM tbl_p p2, tbl_m m2 WHERE netArea = p.netArea AND plantType = '2'  and date = dt and m2.lp = p2.lp AND (inputType = :forecastType) ELSE maxCapacity*(SELECT sum(hour00_01)/sum(maxCapacity) FROM tbl_p p3, tbl_m m3 WHERE electricityArea = p.electricityArea AND plantType = '2'  and date = dt and m3.lp = p3.lp AND (inputType = :forecastType) hour00_01

Comment: You should consider downloading SQL Sentry Plan Explorer and looking at execution plan, also it can generate Anonymous execution plan that you can post without disclosing any information  http://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view

Comment: At a first test when changing to CASE construct I was able to reduce the query time from 2 min 18 secs to 1 min 8 secs. I'll try this with a bigger dataset now to see the difference and will let you know the outcome shortly.

Comment: @VladimirOselsky Thank you for the tip about SqlSentry. I've downloaded it and will see how I can benefit from that.

Comment: @DanBracuk With datasets of 984 rows the query is taking a very long time to run still. It took 10 mins 8 secs to run it . I tried changing the cross join to left join, but get an error message saying "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'." Any ideas how I could further optimize this query?

Comment: @VladimirOselsky I can only post 30.000 rows from Sql sentry here while the extract I have generated 1200000 rows. Should I still post part of the XML here?

Comment: @mediasurface if you run get the actual execution plan in SQL Sentry, you can press `Anonymize` button, than go to `SAVE AS` and select to save as `Execution Plan Files .sqlplan` that will give you XML for entire code. There should no reason for that to be greater than couple hundred lines. You can just copy and paste that XML. Also as alternative you can upload the file to another site and paste the link. File should be under 100k

Comment: @VladimirOselsky Here is a link to the sql plan from sql sentry: https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/d54706cbfbd41ccfa5d6c96d322154b820141218145857/612d938f98f30832d147c00b91bf144920141218145857/f6a554

Answer (score 1):

Based on your execution plan you have one simple reason for poor performance. When you look at execution plan for every column hour00_01, hour00_02 and etc. you doing 2 table scans .8% + .1% than hash match of 3.1% + another .1% for Index Spool. therefore your cost of 4.1% of total execution is repeated 24 times because it is done for every column. Instead of this you should refactor your code to generate one CTE, temp table or table variable that does sum of every column you need. For instance your code instead of individual sub queries will be something like this.

```
SELECT SUM(hour00_01) / SUM(maxCapacity) AS hour00_01
       ,SUM(hour01_02) / SUM(maxCapacity) AS hour01_02
       -- Plus other 22 hours --
    FROM tbl_p p2
    JOIN tbl_m m2
        ON m2.lp = p2.lp
           AND netArea = p.netArea
    WHERE plantType = '2'
        AND date = dt
        AND ( inputType = 'Type' )


SELECT SUM(hour00_01) / SUM(maxCapacity) AS hour00_01
       ,SUM(hour01_02) / SUM(maxCapacity) AS hour01_02
       -- Plus other 22 hours --
    FROM tbl_p p2
    JOIN tbl_m m2
        ON m2.lp = p2.lp
           AND electricityArea = p.electricityArea
    WHERE plantType = '2'
        AND date = dt
        AND ( inputType = 'Type' )
```

if you do this you would get all the sums without having to hit tables multiple times. When optimizing query it is always important to reduce trips to the table. If you do all the sums at once it will same you those extra table scans and only have one hash join for all columns instead of one for each column

Additionally you should consider `SUM() OVER (PARTITION BY` clause that allows you to do in-row calculation without more trips to the table.

Comment: Very interesting observation, it totally makes sense. In your example, you have two queries following eachother, shouldn't there be a UNION between these? And where do I add the part regarding "from AllDates ad cross join tbl_p p"?

Comment: I was just pointing out that you can do each set of `SUM` together instead of only doing one sum per sub query. You can put this into CTE and just join to it and you would have access to all the columns.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this new SQL query working. Can you please help out with this? I tried putting FROM tbl_p p2 JOIN tbl_m m2 ON m2.lp = p2.lp AND netArea = p.netArea WHERE plantType = '2' AND date = dt AND ( inputType = 'Type' ) but then dt is not recognized anymore. I've put the new query in a separate post.